# ASP.NET CheckBox within TemplateField

Tags: c#, asp.net

Trying to get a CheckBox working within a TemplateField but when I put in runat="server" it tells me the server tag is not well formed but when I remove it, it wants me to put it back.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CheckBox Test" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" SortExpression="CheckBoxTest">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbTest" runat="server" Checked="<%# Eval("cbTest") == DBNull.Value ? false : Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("cbTest")) %>" Width="100px" Enabled="false" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbTest2" runat="server" Checked="<%# Eval("cbTest") == DBNull.Value ? false : Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("cbTest")) %>" Width="100px" Enabled="true" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use combination of `single` and `double` quotes for make a well formed server tag.

```
Checked='<%# Eval("cbTest") == DBNull.Value ? false : Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("cbTest")) %>'
```

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I didn't notice that. Will mark as answer as soon as the timer is up.